# use current element in function at jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-visualization

This is my plug-in use for draw google line chart.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.loadLineChart = function(dataArr, title) {

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(dataArr, title) });

        function drawChart(dataArr, title) {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArr);

            var options = {
                title: title
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chat_div')[0]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```

I call this plug-in as following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    var data = '';
    var title = '';

    $('#chart_div').loadLineChart(data, title);
</script>
```

Now i hard code current element chart_div in the plugin. How i use current element in that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a jQuery plugin is just a method of `jQuery.prototype` (which is aliased to `jQuery.fn`), you can refer to the current instance of jQuery inside your plugin with `this`:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.loadLineChart = function(dataArr, title) {
        var $this = this;
        //...
        function drawChart(dataArr, title) {
            //...
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($this[0]);
        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Notice that in this case you will need to store a reference to the current value of `this` in the `loadLineChart` method, since `this` will have a different value in the `drawChart` function.

Answer (score 0):

In a plugin, `this` will refer to the element the plugin is instantiated on. Therefore the following will work for you:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.loadLineChart = function(dataArr, title) {
        var $currentElement = this;

        // rest of your code...

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($currentElement[0]);
    };
})( jQuery );
```

If you were to call your plugin on a group of elements, for example `$(".foo").loadLineChart();` you would need to loop through each of the elements in the `this` collection.

Comment: `this` will be an instance of jQuery since the plugin is a method on `jQuery.prototype` (no need to wrap `this` in jQuery again).

Comment: Yeah, I was just checking that in the API :)